# Google App Engine Java Spring Web service error during deployment

Tags: google-app-engine

I am facing following error during deployment of web service using mvn appengine:update command:

> Blockquote Unable to find the webapp directory /home/zeesh_arif/src/spring-greeting-webservice/master/gs-rest-hateoas/target/gs-rest-hateaos-0.1.0/gs-rest-hateoas-0.1.0
>   usage: AppCfg [options]  [] []

Following is the pom.xml

```
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-rest-hateoas</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
  <directory>${project.basedir}/target/gs-rest-hateaos-${project.version}</directory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.34</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Following is the project directory structure snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

problem fixed, added:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

to pom.xml